# why get this error when trying to inject the Conext?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

if having multiple modules and they all provide the application context,  how to inject the conext into some class (like activity)?

here having two modules, both provide application context,  and the componenet  has getConext() function and some others defined.

the DataModule

```
@Module
class DataModule(@ApplicationContext val mAppContext: Context) {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    internal fun provideAppContext(): Context {
        return mAppContext
    }
    ... ...

    // provide the DataManagerAdapterImpl

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideDataManagerAdapter(dataManagerAdapter: DataManagerAdapterImpl): DataManagerAdapter {
        return dataManagerAdapter
    }
}
```

the UIModule

```
@Module
class UIModule(@ApplicationContext private val applicationContext: Context) {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    internal fun provideAppContext(): Context {
        return applicationContext
    }
    ... ...
}
```

the componenet:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(UIModule::class, DataModule::class))
interface UIComponent {

    @ApplicationContext
    fun getContext(): Context

    fun dataManagerAdapter(): DataManagerAdapter
    ... ...

    fun inject(dataManagerAdapter: DataManagerAdapter)
    fun inject(loginActivity: LoginActivity)
}
```

the injector helper:

```
class DiInjector constructor(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val sUIComponent: UIComponent by lazy {
            DaggerUIComponent.builder()
                    .dataModule(DataModule(appContext))
                    .uIModule(UIModule(appContext))
                    .build()
        }
        ......

        getUIComponent() : UIComponent{
            return sUIComponent
        }
    }
}
```

the class injects context:

```
abstract class DataManagerAdapter {

    @Inject
    lateinit var context: Context
    ... ...
}
```

and its derived class:

```
class DataManagerAdapterImpl @Inject
constructor() : DataManagerAdapter() {

    init {
        DiInjector.getUIComponent().inject(this)  //<== will inject the context
    }
    ......
}
```

and the activity who injects the DataManagerAdapterImpl

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mDataManagerAdapter: DataManagerAdapter

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity)

        // this will get the UIComponent
        DiInjector.getUIComponent().inject(this)  //<== will inject the actual DataManagerAdapterImpl
        ......
    }
    ... ...
}
```

1. if both DataModule and UIModule provide the Context, it will get following error, and it is true that the Componenet's getConext() does not know to get from which module, the DataModule or UIModule.

   ```
          e: ../di/UIComponent.java:23: error: @com.data.scope.ApplicationContext android.content.Context is bound multiple times:
   public abstract android.content.Context getContext();
   ^
   @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @com.data.scope.ApplicationContext @Provides @Singleton android.content.Context com.data.di.module.UIModule.provideAppContext$sample_debug()
   @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @com.data.scope.ApplicationContext @Provides @Singleton android.content.Context com.data.di.module.DataModule.provideAppContext$sample_debug()
   ```
2. if in the DataModule comment out the Context providing part `fun provideAppContext(): Context`,  then now only UIModule provides the context. But it will get different error that trace down to the getContext() part.

not sure why the componenet's getContext() cannot provide the context from `UIModule`, which is now the single provide:

```
e: ../di/component/UIComponent.java:35: error: android.content.Context cannot 
be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
    public abstract com.data.DataManagerAdapter DataManagerAdapter();
    ^
    android.content.Context is injected at
    com.data.DataManagerAdapter.context
    data.DataManagerAdapterImpl is injected at

   com.di.module.DataModule.provideDataManagerAdapter$doubleplay_debug
   (DataManagerAdapter)
    com.data.DataManagerAdapter is provided at
    com.di.component.UIComponent.DataManagerAdapter()
    e: ../di/UIComponent.java:40: error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
^
android.content.Context is injected at
com.data.DataManagerAdapter.context
com.data.DataManagerAdapter is injected at
com.di.component.UIComponent.inject(DataManagerAdapter)
e: ../di/UIComponent.java:43: error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
^
android.content.Context is injected at
com.data.DataManagerAdapter.context
data.DataManagerAdapterImpl is injected at
com.di.module.DataModule.provideDataManagerAdapter$doubleplay_debug(DataManagerAdapter)
com.data.DataManagerAdapter is injected at
com.data.LoginActivity.mAccountManagerAdapter
com.data.LoginActivity is injected at
com.di.component.UIComponent.inject(LoginActivity)
```

===

**Update:**

With the change Mark suggested (put the context as param in the constructor and remove the call of `DiInjector.getUIComponent().inject(this)` in the `DataManagerAdapter::init{} block)`, it still does not work.

```
abstract class DataManagerAdapter(var context: Context) {

// put in constructor
//@Inject
//lateinit var context: Context
... ...
}
```

the sub class

```
class DataManagerAdapterImpl @Inject
constructor(context: Context) : DataManagerAdapter(context) {

init {
// remove it, now context is in constructor's param
//DiInjector.getUIComponent().inject(this)  //<== will inject the context
}
......
}
```

still get error on not able to resolve the conext

```
e: ../di/UIComponent.java:43: error: android.content.Context cannot be 
provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
^
android.content.Context is injected at
com. data.DataManagerAdapterImpl.<init>(context)
    com.data.DataManagerAdapterImpl is injected at

com.di.module.DataModule.
     provideDataManagerAdapter$doubleplay_debug(DataManagerAdapter)
com.data.DataManagerAdapter is injected at
com.data.LoginActivity.mAccountManagerAdapter
com.data.LoginActivity is injected at
com.di.component.UIComponent.inject(LoginActivity)
```

Is this following understanding correct?

the LoginActivity has dependency on the `generic base class DataManagerAdapter` which is resolved by UIComponent's `fun inject(loginActivity: LoginActivity)`.

the `generic base class DataManagerAdapter` is provided by DataModule's

```
fun provideDataManagerAdapter(dataManagerAdapter: DataManagerAdapterImpl): 
   DataManagerAdapter {
    return dataManagerAdapter
},
```

which has dependency on the implementation `sub class DataManagerAdapterImpl`.

the implementation of `sub class DataManagerAdapterImpl` is using constructor injection, so it is provided implicitly.

Now the context is required param in the `DataManagerAdapter(var context: Context)` and the sub class

```
class DataManagerAdapterImpl @Inject  constructor(context: Context) : 
    DataManagerAdapter(context) {}
```

so it has dependency on the context which the UIComponenet has a provide of Context through UIModule's `fun provideAppContext(): Context`.

Why does it still complain  `"android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method"`?

Comment: 1) You cannot provide the same `Object` twice in the same scope unless you have different qualifiers to differentiate the Objects, which is pointelss here as they point to the same `Object` 2) Your subtype `DataManagerAdapterImpl` is using constructor injection - just have a constructor on the super type that takes in a `Context` - the subtype will to forced to override that constructor, remove the `lateinit` field variable.  Constructor injection means you do not need to get the `Component` and call "inject(<myclass>)" -that is only required for classes where you cannot control instantiation

Comment: Thanks Mark Keen! But with the change you suggested (put the context as param in the constructor and remove the call of DiInjector.getUIComponent().inject(this) in the DataManagerAdapter::init{} block), it still does not work.

abstract class DataManagerAdapter(var context: Context) {
    ... ...
}
the sub class

class DataManagerAdapterImpl `@`Inject
    constructor(context: Context) : DataManagerAdapter(context) {
    ......
}
still get error on not able to resolve the conext

error: Context cannot be provided without an Provides-annotated method.